# How can I change the on_release functionality of a KivyMD button using Python code in KivyMD?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

How can we change the `on_release` function of KivyMD button using Python code? I have added a print statement to the KivyMD button initially and I have changed `on_release` function of KivyMD button with Python code but the problem is, it joins my new function to the button instead of replacing its previous function. That mean, it also executes the previous function assigned to the button but I want to change function completely like replacing it with a new function using Python code.

Here is my Python code

```
self.root.ids.btn.on_release = self.new_function
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your initial `on_release` function is set in `kv`, then I don't think you can remove or replace it. I believe the fix is to extend the `Button` class and define the initial `on_release` function in its `__init__()` method. Like this:

```
class MyButt(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.on_release = partial(print, 'hi')
        return super(MyButt, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Then replace that `Button` in your `kv` with `MyButt`, and remove the `on_release:` line fom the `kv`.

Comment: I fixed a silly error that was in my original answer. You can't do `self.on_release = print('hi')`, because that is trying the assign the return value of `print()` to the `on_release` event. rather than the actual method.